# Grive has Problem with libboost library after Update to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, grive

Since I updated Ubuntu to version 19.04 grive is not working anymore. Grive requires libboost in version 1.65.1 but my ubuntu has libboost only in version 1.67.0. 
I already reported this as an issue on the [grive Project](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/issues/272) but there is no action until now.
Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can't you install [libboost1.65-dev in Disco](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libboost1.65-dev)

Comment: I think downgrading libboost is not the best solution because I'm not sure if I break dependencies in other apps which need libboost > 1.65.1.